# Metric space that is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

What are some simple examples of metric spaces that cannot be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$? I've heard there is an example with $4$ points, where two points lie between the other two, but I cannot figure out the details.

Comment: Any metric space $(S, d_S)$ where $S$ has cardinality larger than $c$ is a simple example.

Comment: AB equals to 2, other distances between ABCD are equal to 1. Then both points C, D should be midpoints of AB,  but they do not coincide.

Comment: @NickS, that was cute! There is nothing like a huge hammer.

Comment: (1) It's useful to say "that are not isometric to", since metric spaces are usually considered in many categories (topological, lipschitz, isometric, large-scale lipschitz, etc). (2) It's also useful to say which norm is considered on $\mathbb{R}^n$ since it can matter. (3) The question is ambiguous since it's not clear if it means "not embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some given $n$ (for each $n$ such a question makes sense, and the title rather suggests this interpretation), or not embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$.

Comment: Slightly less huge hammer: an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: Another version would be: a metric space that is not homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: @FedorPetrov: is this obvious? That there is no (unusual) metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that this could hold?

Comment: what do you mean by unusual metric? How should it be related to the algebraic and topological structures of $\mathbb{R}^n$? I meant the Euclidean metric.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. So we are comparing 4 points and the metric you provided and $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Euclidean metric, so I guess that makes sense. So does statements like "In $\mathbb{R}^n$ every Cauchy sequence is convergent" include the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equipped with the Euclidean metric or does it hold for any metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$? There can be different metrics defined for $\mathbb{R}^n$, right?

Answer (score 6):

Although this questions should be closed since it is not a at the research level, let me answer it since the answer is of independent interest.

There is a complete characterization, due to Schoenberg, of finite metric spaces that admit an isometric embedding into a Euclidean space:
[A reference to a characterization of metric spaces admitting an isometric embedding into a Hilbert space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297638/a-reference-to-a-characterization-of-metric-spaces-admitting-an-isometric-embedd).
Any metric space that violates Schoenberg's condition cannot be realized as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A metric space given in a comment of Fedor Petrov is an example.

You can also find a lot of interesting references in fantastic comments to this answer.

Comment: There is a nice [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01954540) by Morgan with an intuitive geometric interpretation of Schoenberg's criterion. However, Morgan seems to have been aware of Schoenberg's 1935 work.

Comment: @TobiasFritz Thank you for the reference I was not aware of Morgan's paper.

Comment: Morgan (1974) quotes a 1928 paper by Menger with the same result. This is very interesting, since it seems that Menger's criterion is the same as Schoenberg's. *Menger, Karl: “Untersuchungen über allgemeine Metrik”, II Math. Ann 100 (1928), p. 113-141*.

Comment: There's yet more discussion of the work of Menger and Schoenberg in this expository paper on distance geometry https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02816

Comment: As well as Blumenthal's 1970 book "Theory and applications of distance geometry".